# How to Bind a JSON Array to view using knockout js mapping plugin

Tags: knockout.js, knockout-mapping-plugin

How can I bind a json array response received from server side to the view using the knockout js mapping plugin ?. The data is received exactly as I have shown here and I don't have any control to alter what the server is returning. [Here](http://jsfiddle.net/shen747/r2Ajr/) is my JSFiddle.

my code as as given below :

***Javascript***

```
var data =
[{"street":"2532 Falkark Dr", "lat":"39.926295", "lng":"-86.012919", "zipcode":"92256"},       {"street":"8558 Appleby Ln", "lat":"39.922742", "lng":"-86.017637", "zipcode":"92256"},{"street":"8537 Rock Hollow Car", "lat":"39.916740", "lng":"-86.017043", "zipcode":"92256"},{"street":"8882 Powderhorn Way", "lat":"39.923866", "lng":"-86.012018", "zipcode":"92256"},{"street":"8820 Starrup Ct", "lat":"39.915676", "lng":"-86.023990", "zipcode":"92256"},{"street":"8545 Woodstone Ct", "lat":"39.915650", "lng":"-86.017014", "zipcode":"92256"},{"street":"8830 Burwack Dr", "lat":"39.924993", "lng":"-86.013454", "zipcode":"92256"},{"street":"8613 Appleby Ln", "lat":"39.921938", "lng":"-86.016539", "zipcode":"92256"},{"street":"8722 Gunpowder Ct", "lat":"39.916807", "lng":"-86.014584", "zipcode":"92256"},{"street":"7888 Beanblossom Car", "lat":"39.904030", "lng":"-86.029995", "zipcode":"92256"},{"street":"2172 Hadway Dr", "lat":"39.921560", "lng":"-86.017160", "zipcode":"92256"},{"street":"2118 Hardwood Ct", "lat":"39.920002", "lng":"-86.046934", "zipcode":"92250"},{"street":"8116 Teel Way", "lat":"39.903596", "lng":"-86.021409", "zipcode":"92256"},{"street":"8232 Castle Farms Rd", "lat":"39.907012", "lng":"-86.026124", "zipcode":"92256"},{"street":"2473 Colony Poante East Dr", "lat":"39.925350", "lng":"-86.049030", "zipcode":"92250"},{"street":"2302 Andaron Ct", "lat":"39.922920", "lng":"-86.048216", "zipcode":"92250"},{"street":"8135 Summertree Ct", "lat":"39.911729", "lng":"-86.024716", "zipcode":"92256"},{"street":"8626 Kruggle Ct", "lat":"39.914703", "lng":"-86.016291", "zipcode":"92256"},{"street":"8475 Wakefaeld Ct", "lat":"39.910430", "lng":"-86.032006", "zipcode":"92256"},{"street":"2416 Haddangton Dr W", "lat":"39.924718", "lng":"-86.015856", "zipcode":"92256"},{"street":"8461 Praarie Dr", "lat":"39.909595", "lng":"-86.026840", "zipcode":"92256"},{"street":"8328 Praarie Dr", "lat":"39.908163", "lng":"-86.026972", "zipcode":"92256"},{"street":"7251 Sprangwater Dr W", "lat":"39.900045", "lng":"-86.026943", "zipcode":"92256"},{"street":"2171 Andaron Dr", "lat":"39.921336", "lng":"-86.048979", "zipcode":"92250"},{"street":"8613 Quarterhorse Dr", "lat":"39.913344", "lng":"-86.023906", "zipcode":"92256"},{"street":"8812 Champaons Dr", "lat":"39.915806", "lng":"-86.022538", "zipcode":"92256"},{"street":"8556 Honeysuckle Way", "lat":"39.912083", "lng":"-86.019654", "zipcode":"92256"},{"street":"8475 Summertree Ln", "lat":"39.911031", "lng":"-86.026843", "zipcode":"92256"},{"street":"8511 Castle Radge Ln", "lat":"39.910708", "lng":"-86.030860", "zipcode":"92256"},{"street":"8112 Stonebranch East Dr", "lat":"39.903251", "lng":"-86.029115", "zipcode":"92256"}]



function ViewModel() {
var self = this;
self.addresses = ko.observableArray([]); 
    ko.mapping.fromJS(data, {}, self.addresses);

}

var viewModel = new ViewModel();

//function binding work order details to view
$(document).ready(function () {
    ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
});
```

***Html***

```
<h3>Knocked Out</h3>
<table class="table table-condensed">

<thead>
<tr>
<th class="span2">Address</th>
<th class="span1">Latitude</th>
<th class="span3">Longitude</th>
<th class="span3">Zip Code</th>
</tr>
</thead>

<tbody data-bind="foreach: addresses">
<tr>
<td data-bind="text: street"></td>
 <td data-bind="text: lat"></td>
 <td data-bind="text: lng"></td>
 <td data-bind="text: zipcode"></td>
 </tr>
 </tbody>
 </table>
```

Any Help is highly appreciated.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/sdTGn/ I don't get the problem with your code, can you elaborate on what you want done? Also, JSON is a data-exchange format you use to serialize array in, what you have in your code is just a JavaScript array object.

Comment: I am trying to do something similar to what I have here  : http://jsfiddle.net/shen747/YQXY4/ . But with an JSON array instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ran your fiddle and saw this in the console:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined
```

This is easily rectified by adding a reference to jQuery in the fiddle.  Then everything seems to be bound properly.

Updated Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/r2Ajr/3/